# Laravel Project setup

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Hi There I have a query on how to setup a laravel project in a team that is connected to LAN, I am using xampp and i have successfully share my htdocs folder, phpmyadmin, so others can access though "filezilla" now I want to know how to share command prompt(cmd as windows users) because laravel project are more based on command line so i need to share my cmd or xampp shell 
eg:- laravel command accessed through cmd :-
"php artisan make:migration create_users_table" 
so server can execute the command successfully but what about other users who are connected to me through LAN

Comment: They just need to know your local IP. Figure out what it is and try connecting to it from another macine on the right port.

Answer (score 1):

They just need to connect your computer through the command line using the IP, Port , username & password. Other thing is you need to set correct permission setting for the project folder.

Comment: i dont get it want you want to say, but thanks i got the solution i just want to install "freesshd" to the server and client can access my terminal through "putty"